# Filtering Divs with buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I’m working on a web site and it’s more like a timeline.

Here is the link:
http://isitimeline.zz.mu/informatika/index.html

I need some JavaScript (or anything else you have in mind) solution for filtering timeline divs by color. We need 4 buttons, one to “Show All” and one for every color (Red, Green and Blue).
E.g. i hit red button and only “red” div are shown and all other divs gets hidden.

Thank you for help.

Comment: Did you try anything? You show no effort on solving the problem

Comment: Tried few solutions from stackoverflow, but without success. Loses whole day on it...

Answer (score 0):

My divs would be something like

```
<div class="content-div green">
</div>
<div class="content-div red">
</div>
```

etc.

Then I would use jQuery to add remove a hidden class eg:

```
$('#button-green').click(function {
    $('.green').removeClass('hidden');
    $('.red').addClass('hidden');
})

$('#button-show-all').click(function {
    $('.content-div').removeClass('hidden');
})
```

And finally the css for class hidden will be:

```
.hidden{ display: none; }
```

Comment: <button type="button" id="button-green">Show Green</button>